# What does it mean "new session has no controlling terminal"?

Tags: linux, terminal, c, session

[This reference](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid) says about creating a new session: The calling process is the leader of the new session, the process group leader of the new process group, and **has no controlling terminal**

So I expected the code below to print nothing, and printf to return an error (something about there being no terminal binding to stdout), but it doesn't. It prints on the terminal from which I run the program

What am I wrong about?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (!fork())
    {
        if (setsid() == -1) // create new session by a child process
            return -1;
        printf("New sesions %d is created\n", getsid(0)); 
    }
    else
        wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It prints to standard output, not directly to the terminal. Why do you think standard output would be closed?

Comment: @Kusalananda I thought that the standard output should be bound to something (terminal, file, socket, etc.). If the standard output is not associated with either a file or a terminal, then where does it write to?

Comment: What I think the issue is is that you believe that a call to `setsid()` disassociates the standard streams from whatever they were connected to before (that it closes them?)  You also think that there needs to be a controlling terminal to do output.  There only needs to be a controlling terminal if you wish to access _the terminal_ (`/dev/tty`), which you don't do from your code.  Unfortunately, I don't fully understand everything about this either, so I can't write a proper answer using all the right words.

Comment: @Kusalananda did I understand correctly that in my case, the standard output of the child process (which created a new session) is associated with the parent process terminal?

Comment: Well, it's certainly not _closed_ by the call to `setsid()`, or the manual would surely mention that.  And if it's not closed, what would it be associated with if not with what it was associated with before the call to `setsid()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the child still inherits the file descriptor and `stdout` is pointing to `/dev/pts/1234` let's say in parent, so it will point to `/dev/pts/1234` in child as well, and that's how kernel knows where to send `stdout`, so it has nothing to do with controlling terminal here if I understand it correctly